# How to test equality of column values and set value in new column

Tags: r

Preface: I am used to Pandas but am new to R. I am sure this question covers very basic R. I have such a little idea I'm not even sure what to search This is most likely a duplicate - Please let me know and I'll gladly delete and go find the answer.

I am aware there is next to no "what have you tried here". If you are even able to point me to some documentation I will delete this and go read it.

Many thanks for your help :)

I have two dataframes:

```
key=  
letter id
A      0
B      1
C      2
```

and

```
data=
name value
A     24
C     46
B     36
C      5
```

I want to write a function to match and find `data$name == key$letter`, and return the corresponding value in `key$id` in a new column in `data`.

The output dataframe would look as so:

```
data
name value id
A     24    0
C     46    2
B     36    1
C      5    2
```

Essentially I want to use `key` as a reference data frame.

I could do this trivially in Python using `np.where` `apply` `match` and `loc` but in R, I have no idea where to begin.

I have read through the following questions on `which` `apply` and `index`, and `compare` but I have been unable to figure out how to write this statement.

[Return indices of rows whose elements (columns) all match a reference vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34158713/return-indices-of-rows-whose-elements-columns-all-match-a-reference-vector)
[Finding the index inside a vector satisfying a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22660149/finding-the-index-inside-a-vector-satisfying-a-condition)
[How to find the indices of an R list meeting multiple criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23137276/how-to-find-the-indices-of-an-r-list-meeting-multiple-criteria)
[Is there an R function for finding the index of an element in a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577727/is-there-an-r-function-for-finding-the-index-of-an-element-in-a-vector)
[Compare two data.frames to find the rows in data.frame 1 that are not present in data.frame 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171426/compare-two-data-frames-to-find-the-rows-in-data-frame-1-that-are-not-present-in)

Can you help?

Comment: Your final link shows `match()`, which is one way to do this. `key$id[match(data$name, key$letter)]`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right

Comment: @Frank  Many thanks for your help, I will take a look :)

Comment: @LyzandeR Many thanks for your help, I will take a look :) Apologies for how simple it is :(

Comment: @Frank Your suggestion worked perfectly. If you put that as an answer I'm happy to +1 and accept.

Comment: @LyzandeR `Merge`, with `all=True` worked for me too. Happy to +1 your answer to if you wanted to write it :) Many thanks for your help, C

Comment: I guess closing it as a dup makes more sense. Happy to help :)

Comment: @LyzandeR Good point. Thanks anyway - glad to join the SO R community :)

Answer (score 0):

```
tt <- match(data$name, key$letter)
data$id <- key$id[tt]
```